# How to recover data from a device with broken touch screen and no OTG support?

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen

A friend of mine owns a ZTE T84, also known as the Telstra Tough Max. Unfortunately, he dropped the phone and cracked the screen which resulted in a non-responding touchscreen. The screen itself does work.

In the meantime, he has bought a new phone, but still wants to restore all his contacts from the old phone. So I promised him to take a look at it.

At first I checked his Gmail account with him to verify if all his contacts were backed up in that account. Unfortunately, that wasn't the case.

I am able to connect the phone to a PC and it is connected in PTP mode, which gives the possibility to copy all the photos but not the rest of the data stored in the phone.

Then I tried to use an OTG cable with a mouse connected to the device. Unfortunately, this didn't work either, because the phone doesn't function as a USB host.

After that, I ended up trying things via the recovery mode menu. I tried to access the device via ADB, but it doesn't show up in there. It looks like USB debugging is not enabled. I noticed, when choosing "Apply update from ADB", it does connect and shows up in `adb devices` as `sideload`. But I can't use `adb shell` from there on, only the sideload things.

When I choose the option "Reboot to bootloader" it gives me a black screen, but I noticed it popped up in device manager and fastboot list it in the devices. However, commands such as `fastboot oem device-info` don't work.

I also tried to wipe the cache partition in the hope that the usb-connection mode would change, but no luck with that.

I did a lot of Googling on this subject but, so far, no luck in finding the solution. Does anyone have an another idea of what I can try to gain control over the phone or at least restore his contacts?